# Binding list of objects to ListView with a UserControl inside, problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, user-controls

I have a **ListView** containing a **UserControl** with a public property **MyPublicProperty** of type **MyType**.

```
public MyType MyPublicProperty{ get; set; }
```

I bind to ListView a list of items of **MyType**

```
listView.DataSource = (List<MyType>) items;
listView.DataBind();
```

In aspx my ListView is defined like this

```
<asp:ListView ID="listView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <uc1:MyControl ID="myControl" runat="server" MyPublicProperty="<%#(MyType)Container.DataItem %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Now what happens is that in MyControl **MyPublicProperty** is not set at the event onDataBinding, and neither after that event.

Do you happen to know why, and a solution for this ??
**EDIT:**
Looking more into the problems I observed that

```
listView.Items[0].DataItem
```

is null after I call **listView.DataBind()**, but the list datasource has more then 1 items.

Comment: I just had to call on MyControl  OnDataBinding, base.OnDataBinding before using MyPublicProperty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the data after it has been bound, you should use the **ItemDataBound** event which will get called for each item of data:

```
listView.ItemDataBound += new EventHandler<ListViewItemEventArgs>(listView_ItemDataBound);
```

Then:

```
private void listView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        MyType data = (MyType)((ListViewDataItem)e.Item).DataItem;

        // Use your data...
    }
}
```

What is it you're trying to achieve? The way you have your code now, the data will be set in the UserControl just fine without any further work from you.

Comment: I used ItemDataBound and it works. But in the old way it still doesn't work. MyPublicProperty is not set after I call **listView.DataBind()**

Comment: How are you checking the status of MyPublicProperty after your DataBind call? Are you finding the control through the Page?

Comment: I am trying to display in the UserControl some values from it, and it is null. I test it in the UserControl at Page_Loading, DataBinding and PagePrerender. Very strange. But if I get the UserControl in the list's event **ItemDataBound** and asign the value to it's property like this: **control.MyPublicProperty = e.Item.DataItem as MyType ;** it works. Maybe it's an ASP.NET bug :)

Comment: Shouldn't be a bug. I've created a UserControl that accepts the property being bound how you've described. MyType contains a string property which I then use a Literal to output in the PreRender event of the UserControl. This works fine.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you need the full namespace of MyType in your ListView, and you omitted the LayoutTemplate. But you may be using .NET 4.0 and not 3.5 so that might no longer be a requirement, I can't remember. Either way you would receive an error about it which you're not doing, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: This behaviour is very strange. None of the above suggestions made a difference. I have both LayoutTemplate and full namespace of MyType. Anyway, thanks for the help. I will just leave it like this :).

Comment: Here's a paste of the simple solution I made, see if it helps - http://pastebin.com/TFKUFyMr